# Ошибка при запуске mongod

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

При запуске:

```
$ sudo mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
```

выходит ошибка:

> 2018-11-09T05:30:36.415+0300 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'

Что делать? В гугле не нашел решения(

Comment: В гугл переводчике надо было искать ;) `$ sudo mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf --sslDisabledProtocols='none'`

Comment: `BadValue: need to enable SSL via the sslMode flag when using SSL configuration parameters
try 'mongod --help' for more information` — выходит такая ошибка(